# Data not binding on edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to implement the CKEditor for a blog.  I've got the Create Blog working fine, but for some reason the Edit Blog page does not display content which already exists.

If I remove the CKEditor.replace script, then the normal EditorFor displays fine. See images below.

I've read lots of posts, as well as the CKEditor documentation, and what I'm doing is supposedly correct.

Is there a trick to get the pre-existing data to show in the CKEDITOR content area?

Here's the JS to add the CKEDITOR

```
<script>CKEDITOR.replace("MainContent")</script>
```

Here's the HTML.

```html
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, 
   new { htmlAttributes = 
          new { @id = "MainContent", @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
```

When the CKEDITOR.replace is used, it looks like this... no data shows in the Content area.

[image]

When the CKEDITOR.replace is removed, it looks like this, the content displays correctly

[image]

Comment: It replaces a textarea. Render your input as such.

Comment: if I change the control to @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content) then the CKEditor does not display.

The issue is not displaying the CKEDITOR, it's getting the content to load into the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I'm not sure why it does not work out of the box the way it is described, but I added a bit of JavaScript and now it's working.  I'd still love input on why it does not work as described.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Blog/Edit',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(Blog),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success == true) {
                    window.location.href = "../Blog";
                }
                else if (data.success == false) {
                    alert("Error occured..!!")
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error occured..!!");
            },
        });
```